# Putting a number on the right hand side without using the equation or align environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering, align

I have a couple of lines which I wish to number and I'm hoping for something like:

Text... \alignright{1} or something like that if it exists to produce

Text...            (1)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `Text...\hfill (1)` would do it, but you are losing one of the prime features of TeX in doing so... the ability to apply a `\label` to the line for later reference, `\ref`.  Note that what I gave is not in math mode (based on how I understood your question).

Comment: I should have been more clear. It is a definition of something mathematical written in words. It is centered, so \hfill removes the centering but putting it outside the center environment but inside the definition environment doesn't format it very well.

Comment: The \hfill is a good thing to know, though. Thanks. I think I have managed to adapt the equation environment to work.

Comment: `\hfill Text...\hfill (1)` will center the text.  Or possibly `\hfill Text...\hfill\llap{(1)}`, if you wish to ignore the width of the label.

Comment: Could you please make an example of what you mean to write instead of “Text”?

Answer (score 0):

Math in words can also be put in equation environments, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amstext}%
% or \usepackage{amstext} that defines \text and is loaded by amsmath

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[47]
  \begin{equation}
    \text{Centered text with equation number.}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]